# overrides the linker symbol with linker script file

Tags: linker

I can override some linker symbol on command line i.e

> arm-none-eabi-gcc **-Wl,--defsym=exit=0 -Wl,--defsym=atexit=0**
>   -mthumb -march=armv7  -T board.ld test.c -0 test

But how can I override this with linker file i.e (how can provide **-Wl,--defsym=exit=0 -Wl,--defsym=atexit=0** through linker script file)

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/assignments.html

Comment: Not related to compilers or C or C++.